# How to prevent server socket from closing when client socket is terminated in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I have a multi-threaded client-server architecture using socket in C.

**Client.c**

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
address.sin_port = 9734;
len = sizeof(address);
result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);
if(result==-1) {
    perror("oops: client1");
    return 1;
}

while(1) {
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    if(strcmp(str,"exit") == 0) close(sockfd); //At this point server terminates
    write(sockfd, str, 100);
    read(sockfd, str, 100);
    printf("from server = %s\n", str);
}
```

**Server.c**

```
int main() {
int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
int server_len, client_len;
struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_address;

server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server_address.sin_port = 9734;
server_len = sizeof(server_address);
bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, server_len);
listen(server_sockfd, 100);

while( (client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&client_address, &client_len)) ) {
    // client_len = sizeof(client_address);
    // client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&client_address, &client_len);
    pthread_t sniffer_thread;
    int *new_sock = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    *new_sock = client_sockfd;

    if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
    {
        perror("could not create thread");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("New thread assigned\n");
    }
// close(server_sockfd);
}

void *connection_handler(void *sock) {
int client_sockfd = *(int *)sock;
char str[100];
while(1) { // If I remove this while loop, it works fine
    printf("server waiting\n");
    read(client_sockfd, str, 100);
    write(client_sockfd, str, 100);
}
}
```

Basically the idea is to have the server running continuously, and new clients can connect and disconnect as they want.

---

The problem is that as soon as a client is either interrupted with a `Ctrl+C` or an "exit" message is sent, the client terminates but the server terminates too. The server should not terminate and instead listen for most incoming socket requests.

Can somebody provide some direction as to what exactly I'm doing wrong? I do not wish fork new processes or use `select()`. It has to be a multi-threaded solution.

**UPDATE:**
I have made some changes to the code, mainly adding more error checking etc. If I remove the while loop in the thread connection handler in `server.c`, the server does not terminate with the client, which is what I want. But I don't want to remove the while loop since that means that the server and client can only send one message before the socket is automatically closed.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you have a memory leak in your program. And other resource leaks as you can theoretically create infinite number of threads which will eat up all your resources. You need to *join* the threads once they are done.

Comment: Regarding your problem, you never check for errors or closed connections anywhere. If the connection is closed then `read` will return `0`. Attempting to use a closed socket further will results in errors.

Comment: you're also not null-terminating your strings or declaring them big enough to fit the NUL in as well.

Comment: I will be refactoring the code in the future to take care of these. Right now my only issue is the fact that the server terminates when the connection with the first client is closed, which doesn't seem to be happening due to the reasons you have mentioned

Comment: `while( (client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&client_address, &client_len)) )` :: `accept()` can return -1, causing the `while` to evaluate as true. You should test against `-1` (and check errno)

Comment: By the way, `client_len` should be initialize before each call to `accept`.

Comment: There is a complete absence of error checking in this code. You cannot write networking code like this. You have to check the result of `socket(), bind(), listen(), accept(), connect(), send(), recv(), read(), write()` for -1 and take appropriate action if you get it, where 'appropriate action' does not mean completely ignoring the error, and you also have to check the result of `read()` and `recv()` for zero and take the appropriate action if you get it, which means closing the socket and ceasing all attempts to use the socket further.

Answer (score 3):

The server crashes because the connection handler doesn't recognize a client disconnect, and attempts to write into the socket with the other side closed. This results in `SIGPIPE`, which default action is to terminate the entire process.

A simple fix is to check the return value from `read`, and if it is `0`, return from the thread without writing.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that the client socket (the one returned by [`accept()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html)) is the same as the server's original socket, the one you're listening on.

This is not true, since `accept()` *creates a new socket* that is dedicated to that client, and connected to the client. There's no use for this socket once the client has left, it should be closed. This will not affect your server's ability to accept more connections.